# Approach to LIS2 on spoj

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was solving problem `LIS2` on spoj http://www.spoj.com/problems/LIS2/.I came across
2D segment tree but I guess it is not suitable for this problem.I read `misof` solution to
`NICEDAY` on spoj which is similar to this problem according to this post:
http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/;jsessionid=F39EBDDC41BEB792536BE044ADC8BA2A?module=Thread&threadID=615154&start=0&mc=2.
Neither can't I understand the link between these two questions neither can I understand
the complexity of misof's solution to `NICEDAY`.

PS:I don't want the whole solution also I don't want any approach through 2D segment tree,
as it will  be too complex for this problem(I have tried)

Answer (score 1):

Think of how you would solve the 1D problem:

```
dp[i] = longest increasing subsequence that ends at position i.
```

For each `i`, we have to append `a[i]` to a `j` such that `dp[j]` is maximum and `a[j] < a[i]`. We can find this efficiently using advanced data structures by changing the definition of our `dp` array:

```
dp[i] = longest increasing subsequence that ends with the VALUE i
```

Now, initially `dp[ a[i] ] = 1` for each position `i`. Then for each element `a[i]`, you need the maximum of `dp[0], dp[1], ..., dp[ a[i] - 1 ]`. Then you have `dp[ a[i] ] = mx + 1`.

You can find this maximum by normalizing your array values (make sure they are all in the interval `[1, n]`). You can do this with a sort. For example, if your array is `42 562 13`, the `n = 3` and your new array will be `2 3 1`.

This can be implemented easily with a segment tree that supports queries and updates for maximums. The time complexity will be `O(n log n)`.

This can be extended quite easily to your problem by using 2D segment trees, obtaining time complexity `O(n log^2 n)`, which should not be too complex at all. This involves using a segment tree whose nodes are also segment trees.

Comment: yes i came across that but 2d segment tree code is not that clean especially for this problem and most of the people I guess have used it solving set , so can you give some hint in that direction.

Comment: @sashasami - it doesn't need to be a segment tree, but it will have to be a 2d tree. It can be any balanced BST that you want, as long as you augment its nodes to give you the maximum in their left subtrees (values smaller than the current node). I don't see a way to solve this without 2d trees, but they do not have to be segment trees.

Answer (score 1):

To me, I don't think we can use 2D Segment Tree for this problem because we'll need up to a 10^5 x 10^5 table for the 2D Segment Tree, which is too large.